# Insert data into HTML5 Web Storage from the server

Tags: html, web-storage

Can I insert data into *Web Storage* from the server, like I do it with cookies by setting a header. By *Web Storage* I mean HTML5 *localeStorage* and *sessionStorage*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. But your server need to inject the code into the page it is serving.

From server this code need to be injected somewhere to the body or an extra javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage[key] = myValue;
</script>
```

Comment: But if the user has JavaScript turned off--nothing will work. Can I work around this situation?

Comment: I don't think you can as localStorage require JavaScript. I don't think much on internet would work for users with js turned off :)

Answer (score 0):

Using C# as an example;

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script>  
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
// Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support!
// Some code.....
}
else
{
// Sorry! No web storage support..
};</script>", true);
```